# Differences in loss between offsetting and rollover futures?

Tags: stocks, trading, stock-markets, futures

For example, you are long/buy a crude oil futures contract in March at the spot price of $100 which expires in June. Then the day before they expire, the spot price of the June contract is $70.

If you offset the position, you will have to sell the contract which makes you lose $30.
If you rollover, you will sell the June contract and buy a July contract. Does it mean that you also lose $30 when you rollover? If right, then what differences between these two options since they have the same loss?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the loss difference between offseting and rollover the contracts?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/124561/what-is-the-loss-difference-between-offseting-and-rollover-the-contracts)

Comment: If you ask the same question in a different post everyday, you're not more likely to get an answer.

Comment: You're also not more likely to get an answer if you put the title in all caps.